# Can Java copy files with the lpProgressRoutine callback?

Tags: java, winapi, progress-bar, nio, jna

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34774495/5645656) that Java NIO's [`Files.copy(Path, Path, CopyOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) method uses the Windows function [`CopyFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) on Windows machines. The documentation for this function describes a `lpProgressRoutine` parameter:

> The address of a callback function of type LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE that is
> called each time another portion of the file has been copied. This
> parameter can be NULL. For more information on the progress callback
> function, see the [CopyProgressRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nc-winbase-lpprogress_routine) function.

I want to leverage this callback to use with a [`JProgressBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html). Is there a way to do this with Java NIO or JNA?

Comment: IMHO the usage of the `CopyFileEx` function is an implementation detail of the current JVM. I don't expect this to be exposed through any public API that you can access because any such API would be non-portable between Windows and probably all other platforms that the JVM can run on.

Comment: Maybe something like `InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
new ProgressMonitorInputStream(
parentComponent,
"Reading " + fileName,
Files.newInputStream(Path.of(fileName))));` See `ProgressMonitorInputStream` javadoc You can probably get more nio into that call too

Comment: @ThomasKläger I was afraid that may be the case.

Comment: What is the problem? `JProgressBar` can be used using the kind of thing I posted above

Comment: @g00se I want to use the native copy function because the target directory is on a remote SMB server and the native functions performed better than using Java input/output streams. I like your solution and will use it for local file operations, but it's not optimal for remote file operations. Also, it monitors how many bytes have been *read*, but not how many have been *transferred* to the remote filesystem.

Comment: Are you sure that callback parameter `CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED` is effectively telling you the size of your target? It's possible that it might be no different from calculating from the copying end. Also, since we're talking about the context of a single thread, the difference between what has been read and what has been copied will narrow, since blocking on write will occur if the destination is slow to transfer